# maximum size of string for encrypt in Openssl RSA

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

The function RSA_public_encrypt requires that the variable where encrypted text will be saved, should have a length of RSA_size(*rsa) bytes.
Now, I need to know how big could be the text to encrypt, because if I crypt a little string (for example "asdasd"), there's no problem, but if I try with a bigger string, just a portion of it it's crypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about `RSA_public_encrypt()`, the docs state it pretty clearly:

> flen must be less than RSA_size(rsa) - 11 for the PKCS #1 v1.5 based padding modes, less than RSA_size(rsa) - 41 for RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING and exactly RSA_size(rsa) for RSA_NO_PADDING.

Remember that these are block cryptos, in the general case you need to split your input into blocks and feed the blocks one at a time to the encryption function.

Comment: thank so much. Just another question. RSA_size() value from what depend? if i call it after RSA_generate_key(1024, 17, NULL, NULL); it returns always 128. why?

Comment: @giozh: 1024 is length in bits of the modulus; 1024/8 = 128 is the length in bytes of the modulus.